# How to use a dynamically linked library from relative path

Tags: go

I would like to use a dynamic C library from a go application, I can build the application but the library is not found at runtime.
Here the structure of my project:

```
src/ctest/
      |- lib/
      |    |- libmylib.so
      |    |- libmylib.h
      |- main.go
```

in main.go I import the .h and .so files:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./lib
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./lib -lmylib
#include <mylib.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.testMyLib()
}
```

I can build the application successfully, but when launched it throws this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmylib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I copy the libmylib.so file in /usr/lib then everything works as expected; however, I would like that my application automatically searches  for the needed library in CURRENT_PATH/lib at runtime without setting environment variables. How can I achieve it?

Comment: See `${SRCDIR}` in the [cgo documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/)

Comment: @JimB I tried it and it does not work. Exactly the same error is thrown at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue adding the `-Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/lib` linker flag to LDFLAGS options in the main.go file:

```
package main
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I${SRCDIR}/lib
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/lib -Wl,-rpath=\$ORIGIN/lib -luiohook
#include <uiohook.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
    C.hook_run()
}
```

Now when the application is executed, it uses also the CURRENT_FOLDER/lib to search for dynamic libraries (CURRENT_FOLDER is the directory where the application executable is executed).

For linux users only:
If the error is still thrown, you need to create a symlink or to rename the XXX.so library to XXX.so.0. In my case it was:

```
src/ctest/
  |- lib/
  |    |- libmylib.so
  |    |- libmylib.so.0 <- symlink to ./libmylib.so
  |    |- libmylib.h
  |- main.go
```

Comment: That did the trick for me - it's worth pointing out that, because the linker is invoked via the gcc front end, you need to use the `-Wl,-rpath=` version rather than `ld`'s own `-R` or `-rpath` option - it won't work without `-Wl,` on the beginning as CGO will reject it.