# standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory on CGO project

Tags: c, docker, go, dockerfile, cgo

I have a Go service that references a C library, and I am getting the following error when trying to run my docker image:

`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory`

This is not a duplicate of [standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" - Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory) as I do not have an entrypoint shell script with CR line endings. Some others on this site suggested setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` at compile time, but I of course can't do that as this is a CGO project.

The C library is installed under `/usr/local/lib/sgp4` in the directories `Linux/IFORT` and `Linux/GFORTRAN`, which contain a bunch of .so files.

An environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /usr/local/lib/sgp4/Linux/IFORT.

Within my project, there is a set of wrapper .h files, and the CGO comments as follows:

[image: go setup]

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```sh
FROM [redacted]/alpine-base:3.17

RUN apk update && \
    apk add curl jq

COPY etc/cfg/propagator.properties /usr/local/[redacted]/etc/cfg/
COPY bin/sgp4 /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4
COPY propagator/wrappers /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/wrappers

# Download library files
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/sgp4/lib
RUN curl --output /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar [redacted]/SGP4.tar
RUN tar -xf /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar -C /usr/local/sgp4/lib
RUN rm /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar
RUN export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/sgp4/lib/Linux/IFORT

RUN chmod a+rx /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4

RUN addgroup [redacted] && adduser -D -H -G [redacted] [redacted]
USER [redacted]:[redacted]

HEALTHCHECK NONE

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4", "-config-file-path=/usr/local/[redacted]/etc/cfg/propagator.properties"]
```

Wondering if my library files contained CR line endings, I tried adding these commands to my Dockerfile, but no luck:

```sh
RUN for filey in $(find /usr/local/sgp4/lib/Linux -type f); do echo $filey; sed -i 's/\r$//g' $filey; done
```

```sh
RUN for filey in $(find /usr/local/sgp4/lib/Linux -type f); do echo $filey; tr -d \r < $filey > tmp.so; mv tmp.so $filey; done
```

Note: I compiled the binary on debian, but am constrained to using Alpine for the Docker image. Issues I encountered when compiling are discussed here: [cgo compiler error, missing library links, librt.so.1 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76717432/cgo-compiler-error-missing-library-links-librt-so-1-not-found)

Comment: Check that you have all `.so` dependencies. Replace the entrypoint with `ldd /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4` and study if there are unmapped libs. And then check each `.so` from those dependencies since they do have dependencies themselves.

Comment: I had such issues with alpine - by default it has no `glibc` and go-produced binaries fail. Installing `gcompat` helped: https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Running_glibc_programs

Comment: `RUN export` doesn't do anything; do you need to `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`?  (Also see [docker ENV vs RUN export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379393/docker-env-vs-run-export).)  If the system can't find the C shared libraries that will result in a "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: @PakUula Interesting, I installed `gcompat` and now the `no such file or directory` log is gone. Now there are no logs at all, just immediate crash loop.

Comment: @PakUula Running `ldd` on the binary gives a `bash: ./sgp4: cannot execute: required file not found` error.

Comment: I'd recommend using a Debian, e.g. `debian:11-slim`. Alpine is a very specific image, a lot was sacrificed for the minimal footprint. Slim debian is just 80 Mb, and it is the real Linux server.

Answer (score 4):

A way to solve the *runtime* issue would be to switch to a glibc-based Docker image such as Debian slim or [`jeanblanchard/docker-alpine-glibc`](https://github.com/jeanblanchard/docker-alpine-glibc), because your Go binary and its CGO dependencies were built against glibc.

Using [jeanblanchard/alpine-glibc](https://hub.docker.com/r/jeanblanchard/alpine-glibc), since it is still based on Alpine:

```
FROM jeanblanchard/alpine-glibc:3.18

RUN apk update && \
    apk add curl jq

COPY etc/cfg/propagator.properties /usr/local/[redacted]/etc/cfg/
COPY bin/sgp4 /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4
COPY propagator/wrappers /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/wrappers

# Download library files
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/sgp4/lib
RUN curl --output /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar [redacted]/SGP4.tar
RUN tar -xf /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar -C /usr/local/sgp4/lib
RUN rm /usr/local/sgp4/lib/SGP4.tar
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/sgp4/lib/Linux/IFORT

RUN chmod a+rx /usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4

RUN addgroup [redacted] && adduser -D -H -G [redacted] [redacted]
USER [redacted]:[redacted]

HEALTHCHECK NONE

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/[redacted]/bin/sgp4", "-config-file-path=/usr/local/[redacted]/etc/cfg/propagator.properties"]
```

This base image maintains the small footprint of Alpine but also has the compatibility of glibc, which should make it compatible with your CGO binary.

Switching to this Dockerfile and rebuilding your image should solve the "exec user process caused: no such file or directory" error, as well as the "required file not found" error from `ldd`.